# Reverse-engineering conditional output for a function definition

Tags: python, function, math, primes

I have defined a function to generate a list of prime numbers less than or equal to a given input which you can specify, based on the sieve of eratosthenes.

```
def eratosthenes(max_num):
    primes = list(range(2,max_num+1))
    for i in primes:
        j=2
        while i*j<= primes[-1]:
            if i*j in primes:
                primes.remove(i*j)
            j=j+1
    return primes
```

Now, if I wanted to find out which prime would be the 50th in the list, such that

```
len(primes) = 50
```

How would I go about this? Is it possible to reverse-engineer a defined function in this way?

Comment: @TomKarzes Okay. This wasn't what I was asking for help with, but thanks.

Comment: In general there's no easy way to know the value of the nth prime without first finding all previous primes.  Also, the calls to `remove` in the inner loop, make is a very inefficient implementation.  Normally removing a prime from a sieve should be a constant-time operation, not a linear one.

Comment: You will get the 50th value from the list just with `eratosthenes(300)[49]`. The counting of indices starts from zero, therefore 50th value can be extracted with list index value 49.

Comment: Note that while your algorithm is similar to the Sieve, it has _much worse_ complexity. Usually, you'd have an array of True/False values, and just flip that value to False for multiples of primes. But instead, you check whether the current value is still in the list, and then remove it. Both those steps have O(n) complexity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get the 50th value from the list just with `eratosthenes(300)[49]`:

```py
def eratosthenes(max_num):
    primes = list(range(2,max_num+1))
    for i in primes:
        j=2
        while i*j<= primes[-1]:
            if i*j in primes:
                primes.remove(i*j)
            j=j+1
    return primes

print(eratosthenes(300))
print(eratosthenes(300)[49])
```

which will yield

```
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199, 211, 223, 227, 229, 233, 239, 241, 251, 257, 263, 269, 271, 277, 281, 283, 293]
229
```

The counting of indices starts from zero, therefore 50th value can be extracted with list index value 49.

Then if you would like to limit then length of the list to 50, you may reverse-engineer by calling the function many times until the condition is met:

```py
i = 2
while True:
    primes = eratosthenes(i)
    if len(primes) >= 50:
        break
    i = i + 1
 
print(i)
print(len(primes))
print(primes[49])
```

which yields

```
229
50
229
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you call the function in a loop with increasingly large max numbers until the length of the output is 50, then print out the last item in the output?

Comment: Nice idea, how would I go about trying this? I am very new to Python so a bit slow on a few things.

Comment: Which part are you unsure about? (Calling the function? Incrementing the max number? Etc)